# Validation across multiple fields in JSF/PrimeFaces

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I need to validate across multiple fields in such a way that validation should be violated only when one of the given fields is violated.

It is distinct from cross field validation in which a value of one field is dependent upon the value(s) of one or more of the rest of the fields.

Given below a simple scenario.

```
<p:inputText id="txt1" value="#{testBean.txt1}" required="false" maxlength="45"/>
<p:inputText id="txt2" value="#{testBean.txt2}" required="false" maxlength="45"/>
<p:inputText id="txt3" value="#{testBean.txt3}" required="false" maxlength="45"/>

<p:commandButton id="btnSubmit" actionListener="#{testBean.insert}" 
                 icon="ui-icon-check" value="Save"/>
```

In which, validation violation should be occurred only when one of the given three text fields is left blank. If anyone of them is filled with a value then, all should be validated. In which case, validation should not be violated.

How to proceed with this scenario? Does JSF/PrimeFaces provide some way to perform validation in this way?

Comment: Hi mate, I would like to know the advantages, problems, performances,  enhances, or just is a following the standar, etc. the validation with validators instead of the validation with the managed bean? It according the answer @Fernando Paladini. Is there others reasons in addition you have said? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a hard time in wrapping my head around your concrete functional requirement, but I believe you're looking for "all or none" validation. I.e. either all fields should be blank, or all fields should be filled. JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a validator for exactly this purpose, the [`<o:validateAllOrNone>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateAllOrNone).

Here's how you could use it:

```
<p:inputText id="txt1" value="#{testBean.txt1}" maxlength="45" />
<p:inputText id="txt2" value="#{testBean.txt2}" maxlength="45" />
<p:inputText id="txt3" value="#{testBean.txt3}" maxlength="45" />
<o:validateAllOrNone components="txt1 txt2 txt3" />
```

Answer (score 2):

### Of course!

[Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) provide a lot of ways that can satisfact you. First of all, you can make validations in your MBean method. In your case, you're calling `insert` method, so you can do something like this:

```
public String insert(){

   boolean error = false;
   if(txt1.isEmpty()){
        error = true;
   }

   if(txt2.isEmpty()){
        error = true;
   }

   if(txt3.isEmpty()){
        error = true;
   }

   if(error == true){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"Empty fields!", "Insert something in at least one input!"));
        return null;
   }else{
        return "myPage"
   }
}
```

Note that you can improve the validations by yourself, following your needs. You can also change the message from:

```
FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN
```

to:

```
FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO
FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR
FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL
```

What can give your application a better error message.

---

**Before this works, add this above your input fields:**

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

[image]
Probably this will work like a charm! If you're interested, check the [Primefaces Messages showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf), where you can find some examples and understand better how `<p:messages>` works. 
Also, feel free to check `<p:growl>`, that in my opinion is a lot better than simple messages. Check out the [growl](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/growl.jsf) here.

[image]

Hope I helped you (:

Comment: If you have any question, feel free to ask (:

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a way to perform validation through validator(s). Performing validation in JSF managed beans themselves is dreadful. Moreover, I have over 15 such fields on a page which require so many such conditional checks which is tedious. I hope JSF/PrimeFaces should have a fair way to perform this kind of validations. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Tiny, I don't understood your question. I tought that you needed a way to check if all fields are blank, but if one ore more than one are selected, isn't a problem. @Balusc can understand your question better than me, sorry if I didn't answer with you need :/